# Best way to store temp data as a stack and removing older one from the list

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, combobox

Using C# and Framework 4.5 I have designed a Windows Desktop app for an employer (I'm a private freelance) the application is receiving and analyzing litterally ton of data.

currently, the thread reading it, store the message in a hidden and disabled (enabled=false) ComboBox in order to avoid delay. another thread (Timer) remove the first item in ComboBox and store message in a Database and loop until there is nothign left in ComboBox.

Is there another way instead of ComboBox to store that Data (string) and remove "older" one 
currently using

`strMessage =cmbMessages.Items[0].ToString();
            cmbMessages.Items.RemoveAt(0);`

I thought about collection or dictionnary...  collection is not fast and dictionnary... well... should it be used like that? (not better solution then ComboBox to my knowledge)

What you all think ?

Comment: You just want a list of items?  Why not a `List<T>`?  A `Queue<T>`?  Do these items need to be in the UI for some reason?  It's not really clear what the actual problem is here.

Comment: Start by looking into data binding. UI controls are terrible replacements for variables (including collection)

Comment: Storing temporary data in a UI control is .. well, *crazy*. Yes, you should use a collection of some kind. `Queue<string>` sounds good. If you are actually multithreading, then perhaps [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) would be better.

Comment: Plutonix Oct 17 at 23:31:  collection is way tooo slow to handle the kind of trafic that I'm handling. I tried it and it's about 52times (tested on the compiled version with a program that test quantity of information stored in database for a given time) slower then combobox.additem  also, the collection couldn't handle the speed requirement, WebSocket emit "warning" when message event handler time exceed 100ms and collection triggered theses warning from time to time depending on the flow of information I'm reading

Comment: Plutonix Oct 17 at 23:31: same thing... I'm using direct Access API with Ado.Net RecordSet, not with datareader.  data binding object is buggy and too slow. wayyyy too slow.

Comment: David Oct 17 at 23:27 : ok thanks, I'll look into List and Queue and come back.

Comment: Blorgbeard Oct 18 at 0:15: yes my WebSocket is in a different thread.  I'll look at ConcurrentQueue.

Comment: I'll look at all your proposed solution and test them against my speed tool tester.  I'll post the result with my code so if I did something wrong that prevent faster speed you'll be able to correct my foolisheness :)  thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to leave the terms "police" and "monitoring" out of any questions or answers you post. There are people who may not help you on those grounds alone. Use terminology such as "my employer" and "security software" to avoid all that.

It's not exactly clear if you're using [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx) or [WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx). Both have a property named `Items`. Please specify in future questions. There are sometimes different solutions available depending on what framework you're using.

As commenters have noted, your method of using the ComboBox as a storage object is unorthodox. It's usually problematic because simply touching UI elements may cause side effects(in this case possibly a layout pass and refresh). That's a lot of baggage.

The data flow you have described is best represented as a queue. Data comes in, data goes out, in the order it was added. Use a [Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're sure the data will only flow through one thread or a [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) if not. Periodically update the ComboBox from the queue and you're good to go.

On a different note, you should consider a different UI control. I can imagine navigating a ComboBox and seeing the options flow in and out of it being a pain to deal with. Perhaps a ListBox is more appropriate.

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice...  but for thoses who don't want to answer because I'm on the right side of the law, I don't really care.  I do care about not elevate any negative emotion from reader thought and I'll take your advise under consideration for my futur post.  thanks.

Comment: I'm using WinForm and using Framework 4.5 (VS Studio 2017 default) the "ComboBox is hidden and Enable=False"  this take care of any refresh problem.  I use this method since prehistoric time because at that time, "Items" property didn't existed.  I need to build several of theses list, so I guess I cannot rely on property of object without need to create many object right ?  so it became same as using visual object like ComboBox no ?

Comment: as for the "queue" I'm not familiar with it, I'll google it...  The data is coming out of a WebSocket that make connection to...  whatever... and I currently store it in ComboBox.  advantage I got, I don't have to remove object (text) in the order it got in because I can "search" the ComboBox with Api and treat some text first as priority... does "Queue" allow that ?

Comment: finally, last paragraphe, ComboBox is better then ListBox in my case since control is hidden and disable.  never shown... I prever thoses control take as little place on my screen in design time.

Comment: @VbNetMatrixEnr It's not about being on the right or wrong side of the law. Good people are sometimes spied on by authorities and it rightfully creeps them out. The point was "police" and "monitoring" are terms that easily trigger discomfort in discussion. Using different terminology will likely net you more responses.

Comment: @VbNetMatrixEnr. To be frank, queues, stacks, and many other data structures are some of the first you should have learned about in this field. You **need** to learn about them if you want to be a long term software developer. 


You should never use UI controls as a storage medium, as almost all of their properties affect either layout or rendering(with the exception of properties like [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: @VbNetMatrixEnr. In summary, the idea is: 1) Pass data(i.e. from web socket) into the most appropriate data structure([Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) in your case). 2) Process the data, [adding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t249c2y7(v=vs.110).aspx) & [removing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c8bzx97(v=vs.110).aspx) as needed.

Comment: @ Koby Duck thanks, I did implement Queue <string>.  somehow it seem slower then my previous API method with ComboBox but I didn't made real (tested) comparaison yet.  it does work though, I'll post the speed result as soon as I got time to make the test.  thanks again,  BTW, I got commercial product on the market for last 20 years.  I just recently switched to C#, in past, we didn't had object like Queue and it was common to use hidden UI element to do some work.  ComboBox can be used with API to speed it up by over 1000%